# Conditional ForeColor of GridView Label in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, formatting

I have the following in my asp Label:

```
ForeColor='<%# Eval("Comportement").Equals(3) ? System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff4c4c") : System.Drawing.Color.Empty %>
```

It works fine if the value equals 3 but I want to format if the value is lower than 3. Plus I need to manage a possible null, which is throwing me an error with the above.

Code behind would be ok if simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

```
ForeColor='<%# !Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("Comportement")) && Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Comportement")) < 3 ? System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff4c4c") : System.Drawing.Color.Empty %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```
ForeColor='<%# checkComportement(Eval("Comportement")) %>'

Public Function checkComportement(ByVal val As Integer) As String
     If val = 3 Then
        Return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff4c4c")
     Else
        If val = 0 Then
            // Manage null value
        ElseIf val < 3 Then
            Return System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff4c4c")
        Else
            ...
        End If
     End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in C#

```
private System.Drawing.Color GetColor(string input) 
{
    System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && int.TryParse(input, out int parsedInput) && parsedInput < 3)
    {
        color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff4c4c");
    }
    return color;
}
```